# Congratulations, Ross Millikan!

Tags: discussion, specific-user, celebration

Many congratulations to [Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1827/ross-millikan) on reaching 100000 reputation points. Very well deserved.

Comment: Congratulations , Ross !

Comment: Congratulations on your many concise solutions that go directly to the heart of the matter.

Comment: He has helped me out from time to time!  Thanks for your help, Ross!

Comment: Excellent! ${}{}{}$

Comment: Well done, thanks for all the advice/input to the mathophyllies on this forum

Comment: 50th +1 for this post! Congrats, Ross. :)

Answer (score 12):

$$\text{Congrats, Ross!}$$

Vote this answer up to prevent the Community bot from bumping this question periodically.

Comment: What's wrong with bumping this question periodically? or even aperiodically?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought that's common understanding after I received [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8662/19341) back then...

Comment: You might be right. I just don't see any problem with being reminded occasionally to congratulate Ross.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It will be funny when you congratulate him for 100K, after he has already crossed 500K.

Comment: @gerry feel to add some personal words to Ross in an answer from time to time...